# Uppercase word in glossary, lowercase in text

Tags: glossaries, capitalization

Is it possible to write a word in uppercase in the glossaries but in lowercase in the text?
I could use `\glslink` instead of `\gls`, but is there no better solution?

Here is an example to clarify what I want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{lowercase}{name={lowercase}, description={In the glossary, this word should be capitalized}}
\newglossaryentry{uppercase}{name={Uppercase}, description={This word is capitalized}}

\begin{document}

Should both be lowercase: \gls{lowercase}, \gls{uppercase}.

Workaround: \gls{lowercase}, \glslink{uppercase}{uppercase}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This yields:

```
Should both be lowercase: lowercase, Uppercase.
Workaround: lowercase, uppercase. 

Glossary
lowercase In the glossary, this word should be capitalized. 1
Uppercase This word is capitalized. 1
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a simple solution. You can set the text that appears in the glossary and the text that appears in the... text separatly.

```
\newglossaryentry{uppercase}{
    name={Uppercase},
    text={uppercase},
    description={Appears uppercase in the glossary and lowercase in the text}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For future users encountering same trouble:

I ran into the problem myself and found this question and its [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/howto-achieve-capitalized-description-in-glossary-table). @Nitram's solution was useful in the case of a first word defined as a macro. However:

- I didn't want to duplicate all the name entries,
- I did want to keep control of what is capitalized and what isn't (case of mathematical symbols as first characters),
- I wanted to keep the usual behaviour if nothing is specifically asked.

From an answer by @nicola-talbot [there](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9966), I found a simple redefinition that does the trick:

```
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[2][]{\capitalisewords{#1}\xspace#2}
```

Examples:

Usage: outputs "First word capitalized" in the glossary, and \gls{firstexample} in-text outputs "first word capitalized":

```
\newglossaryentry{firstexample}{
  name={first}{word capitalized}
}
```

This won't work with a macro (will capitalize whole word), hence use of text field:

```
\newglossaryentry{boite}{
  name={\Boite de valeurs},
  text={\boite de valeurs}
}
```

I have maths first, normal use of name: both in the glossary and in-text \gls{firstexample} output "$i$-th blabla":

```
\newglossaryentry{iblabla}{
  name={$i$-th blabla}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've used [Nicola's answer](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=94372#p94372), since none of the answers here worked for me.

The `glossaries-extra` package allows to easily setup the capitalization with `firstuc`.
I didn't had to change much of my previews code, nor calls. Just change the package and add the following code:

```
\setglossarystyle{long}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
```

Comment: @Sndn I think you could consider reading about the package `mfirstuc` and also this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304123/75648

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use both upper and lower case in the text;`\Gls{}` will give the capitalized word or term, as in the beginning of the sentence. In other locations, `\gls{}` can also be used for the lowercase form. See section 3 of the [beginner's guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf). I'm not sure if this exactly addresses the question asked, but it is a common usage for which people might find this question.