# Acronyms capitalized, no dot at the end together with Symbols

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

**UPDATE** 2014-11-20: Found a solution for the dot inside [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Remove_the_point). You have to use `\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}`.

---

I want my abbreviations to be all capitalized and without dot at the end. 
At the moment it looks like this.

[image: abbreviations]

There should also be no dot for symbols, which looks similar:
[image: symbols]

Using both inside the text shouldn't change. The terms should still be lower case as in:

[image: text]

**My MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ipp}{IPP}{integer programming problem}
\newacronym{mipp}{MIPP}{mixed-integer programming problem}
\newacronym{bpmn}{BPMN}{Business Process Model and Notation}
\newacronym{omg}{OMG}{Object Management Group}

\newglossaryentry{symb:delta}{
    sort={3},
    name={$\Delta$},
    first={$\Delta$},
    text={$\Delta$},
    description={Difference between two observations},
    type=symbolslist
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:n}{
    sort={3},
    name={$n$},
    first={$n$},
    text={$n$},
    description={Number of replications of a simulation},
    type=symbolslist
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long ,title=Abbreviations, toctitle=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long ,title=Symbols]

\clearpage

Hello World

\textbf{Acro:} \\
\gls{ipp} \\
\gls{mipp} \\
\gls{bpmn} \\
\gls{omg} \\

\textbf{Sym:} \\
\gls{symb:delta} \\
\gls{symb:n} \\

\end{document}
```

Please make sure to run it with `makeindex`:

```
pdflatex %name%
makeindex %name%.idx -t %name%.ilg -o %name%.ind
makeindex -s %name%.ist -t %name%.alg -o %name%.acr %name%.acn
makeindex -s %name%.ist -t %name%.glg -o %name%.gls %name%.glo
makeindex -s %name%.ist -t %name%.slg -o %name%.syi %name%.syg
pdflatex %latex_cmd%
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There is a much easier way, than showed by Iony.

According to [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Remove_the_point), just use

```
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
```

and the dots are gone..

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/howto-achieve-capitalized-description-in-glossary-table) the problem was solved, using the `description` tag as a workaround.

[image]

MWE for solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[acronym,description,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[description=This is a test]{test}{Test}{this is a test}
\newacronym[description=Operating Room]{or}{OR}{operating room}
\newacronym[description=Electrocardiogram]{ecg}{ECG}{electrocardiogram}


\newglossaryentry{web}{
  name={World Wide Web},
  first={World Wide Web (WWW)},
  text={WWW},
  description={A distributed system of linked hypertext documents}
}
\begin{document}

Here comes \gls{test}

Here comes \gls{web}

Here comes \gls{or}

Here comes \gls{ecg}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary
\end{document}
```