# acro capitalized sections

Tags: acro

For a phrase that is not a proper name, I want to have the first letter of each word uncapitalized except when it starts off a sentence, in which case the very first letter of the phrase is capitalized. But that its not working with `acro`. This code is the one below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{CNO}{
  short = CNO ,
  long  = Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones ,
  class = acro
  }


% class `nomencl': nomenclature
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{
  short = \ensuremath{e_0} ,
  long  = Esperanza de vida al nacer ,
  sort  = e_0 ,
  class = nomencl
  }


\begin{document}
\section*{List of acronyms}
\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{List of acronyms}

\ac{evn} Si yo vengo escribien y el \ac{CNO} aperece primero y luego \ac{CNO}, \ac{ONU} and \ac{evn} are abbreviations whereas \ac{e0}.

\printacronyms

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]

\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]

\printacronyms[include-classes=acro,name=Acronimos]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code shorter and compilable and please explain again, what you want to get. What is a "phrase that is not a proper name"? Your example should show the acronyms at the start of a sentence and in between a sentence and clearly show the misbehaviour. At least, I believe that is the problem you are having right now.

Comment: the problem that i have its that the e0 acronymus appears with capital E in this sentence, when i wanted with e lower case

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

% class `nomencl': nomenclature
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{
  short = \ensuremath{e_0} ,
  long  = Esperanza de vida al nacer ,
  sort  = e_0 ,
  }


\begin{document}


the problem that i have its that the e0 acronymus appears with capital E in this sentence, when i wante with e lower case. some text \ac{e0}.

\printacronyms


\end{document}

Comment: But I do not see any difference between `class = nomencl` and `class = acro`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79907

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}% provides \capitalisewords

\acsetup{
  uc-cmd = \capitalisewords ,
  list-caps = true
}
\MFUnocap{de}% prevent `de' from being capitalised

% class `abbrev': abbreviations:
\DeclareAcronym{CNO}{
  short = CNO ,
  long  = clasificador nacional de ocupaciones ,
  class = acro
}

% class `nomencl': nomenclature
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{
  short = \ensuremath{e_0} ,
  long  = {{esperanza de vida al nacer}} , % two sets of braces!
  sort  = e_0 ,
  class = nomencl
}


\begin{document}

\Ac{CNO} foo. Pero si \ac{e0} bar

\bigskip

\acf{CNO} vs \Acf{CNO} \par
\acf{e0} vs \Acf{e0}

\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]

\printacronyms[include-classes=acro,name=Acronimos]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right, you are looking for the command `\Ac{}` which has to be used in the beginning of a sentence.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{CNO}{
  short = CNO ,
  long  = Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones
  }
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{
  short = \ensuremath{e_0} ,
  long  = esperanza de vida al nacer ,
  sort  = e_0
  }

\begin{document}
\Ac{CNO} foo. \Ac{e0} bar, \ac{CNO} foo \ac{e0} bar.
\end{document}
```

---

If you are talking about the problem of capitalized form for the list of acronyms, you can try:

```
\let\firstchar\lowercase
\let\oldprintacronyms\printacronyms
\def\printacronyms{\let\firstchar\uppercase\oldprintacronyms}

\DeclareAcronym{e0}{ short = \ensuremath{e_0} , long = \firstchar{e}speranza de vida al nacer , sort = e_0 }
```

Comment: No it's not. I dont want to have a capitalized E when I call the \{e0} at the end of my sentence. I want esperanza de vida instead of Esperanza...

Comment: That's what my MWE does. If not on your machine, we have to compare versions

Comment: whats its MWE? I dont have any idea of what that is

Comment: @NicolásSacco: You are not really providing assistance for users willing to help you: Here is the definition of a MWE: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Sorry Christian. What im trying to do it's to have a non capital E at the end of the scrip: % arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{CNO}{
  short = CNO ,
  long  = Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones
  }
\DeclareAcronym{e0}{
  short = \ensuremath{e_0} ,
  long  = Esperanza de vida al nacer ,
  sort  = e_0
  }
\begin{document}
\Ac{CNO} foo. Pero si \ac{e0} bar.
\end{document}
% I want this text Clasificador Nacional de Ocupaciones (CNO) foo. Pero si esperanza de vida al nacer (e0) bar. Without Esperanza with the capital E, just the e....

Comment: @NicolásSacco You did not copy all of my code. You have to define `long  = esperanza de vida al nacer` and use `\ac{e0}`. If you use it in the beginning of a sentence, use `\Ac{e0}`