# Title case for acronym in section titles together with hyperref

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, acro, uppercase

Using the `acro` package I want to use the long version of an acronym as a section title.
However, as I title case them, the acronym should also be title cased while being lowercase in the normal text.
Doing this with `[uppercase/cmd=\ecapitalisewords]` works fine for the displayed text, but hyperref complains and the resulting bookmark name in the pdf is `uppercase/cmd=]MFA`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro,mwe,mfirstuc,hyperref}

\DeclareAcronym{MFA}{short=MFA, long=my fancy acronym}

\begin{document}

\section{\Aclp*{MFA}}

To title case the section title I want to use \Aclp*[uppercase/cmd=\ecapitalisewords]{MFA}.
However, it results in a hyperref warning:

\begin{verbatim}
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\ecapitalisewords' on input line 18.
\end{verbatim}

\section{\Aclp*[uppercase/cmd=\ecapitalisewords]{MFA}} % <- This is line 18

\end{document}
```

I found [a different answer (from the package author)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284263/28449) but it is nearly eight years old, and the proposed solution does not work for me:

1. The used `\capitalisewords` doesn't do anything for me, I have to use the expanding version of the macro.
2. The option `list-caps` which seems to tell `acro` to capitalize all words individually does not exist anymore, and searching for something similar in the documentation does not give any results.

After some more fiddling around, I found something that works for me but is not 100% my desired outcome:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro,mwe,mfirstuc,hyperref}

\DeclareAcronym{MFA}{short=MFA, long=my fancy acronym}
\AddToHook{cmd/subsection/before}{\acsetup{uppercase/cmd=\ecapitalisewords}}
\AddToHook{cmd/subsectionmark/after}{\acsetup{uppercase/first}}

\begin{document}

\section{\Aclp*{MFA}}
\Aclp*{MFA}

\subsection{\Aclp*{MFA}}
\Aclp*{MFA}

\end{document}
```

What I do here is, to automatically set the `uppercase/cmd` to the desired command before a `\section` is created and set it back to the standard value after it is done ([see this post telling us why we can't use the `cmd/subsection/after` hook and suggesting `subsectionmark` instead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682938/28449)).
In the example code we will see that the `section` renders as **My fancy acronyms** while the subsection renders as **My Fancy Acronyms** just as desired and the paragraph after the `subsection` is also back to normal.

*The drawback:* The string that ends up in the PDF table of contents is **My fancy acronyms** for both the section and subsection. For me this is okay, as I don't care *that* much about the correct capitalization in the PDF toc.

Comment: well it is hard. acro makes quite an effort to get something in the bookmarks, but if you use an optional argument this is no longer expandable and then it fails. \ecapitalisewords is not expandable either and removed by hyperref too.  While it is possible to handle all this with hooks and the expandable text commands in expl3, getting all the variants right (and resetting in subsection) is not trivial, and unless you have lots of them, I would simply write `\texorpdfstring{\Aclp*[uppercase/cmd=\ecapitalisewords]{MFA}}{A Fancy Acronym}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. And you're right, this seems like the most reasonable approach.