# Uppercase word in acronyms, lowercase in text

Tags: acronyms, capitalization, glossary

My issue is similar to this post:
[Uppercase word in glossary, lowercase in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69567/uppercase-word-in-glossary-lowercase-in-text/69569#69569?newreg=8ad67d69cddf498d8d8dbd2ec7dbfbf7)

I would like to do the same like Nitram provided for the glossary (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69569/282853), but for acronyms. How can I do this?

EDIT (and probably solved): I found a workaround by using `\glsdisp{}{}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.